# Retrieving Multiple Words using PHP's $_GET function

Tags: php, get

I have a site that offers a keyword search. The user can perform a search by either selecting from a set of pre-defined keywords displayed as hyperlinks or utilize a search form on the same page.

When the user searches for **Russian Blue Cat**, the following is added to the page URL:

If using the pre-defined **hyperlink** search term, then **?keywords=Russian%20Blue%20Cat** is added to the URL as follows:

```
  http://mydomain.com/index.php?keywords=Russian%20Blue%20Cat
```

If using the **search form**, then **?keywords=Russian+Blue+Cat** is added to the URL as follows:

```
 http://mydomain.com/index.php?keywords=russian+blue+cat
```

The following $_GET line of code is placed within **two** PHP files, the original **index.php** file that contain both the pre-defined hyperlink search terms and the search form and another PHP file called **process.php** that utilizes the keywords for another process.

```
  if(empty($_GET['keywords'])){$keywords = '';} else {$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];}
```

The above $_GET line of code contained within the **index.php** file works properly and retrieves all three keywords. In this case the words **Russian Blue Cat** is retrieved.

The above $_GET line of code contained within the **process.php** file does not work properly and only retrieves the first of the three keywords. In this case only the word **Russian** is retrieved.

Is there a simple or proper way to fix this such that all keywords are retrieved properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: not clear to me how the search terms are passed from index.php to process.php

Comment: Please show `var_dump($_GET)` in both files. This sound more like a bad request to me, with unescaped spaces.

Comment: For the hyperlink thay are passed as <a class="search-terms" href="?keywords=russian blue cat">russian blue cat</a>

For thes Search form, they are passed via the form's <input class="search" type="text" name="keywords" value="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />

Comment: var_dump($_GET) for both files. For the index.php, array(2) { ["topic"]=> string(25) "LA_Los_Angeles-California" ["keywords"]=> string(12) "russian blue" }, For the process.php, array(5) { ["XMLFILE"]=> string(84) "http://mysite.com/search/pet?query=russian+blue&srchType=A&format=syn" ["TEMPLATE"]=> string(39) "http://mysite.com/template.html" ["MAXITEMS"]=> string(3) "100" ["topic"]=> string(25) "LA_Los_Angeles-California" ["keywords"]=> string(7) "russian" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the string '%20' and if present, explode by '%20'. Otherwise, check for the presence of a plus sign and explode by it instead.

This method is agnostic of the differing input format from the two sources entering the same script.

The caveat is that the string '%20' or the character '+' cannot occur inside a word in the other format or you will get unusual behavior.

```
$keyword = array();
if(stripos($keywords,"%20")) {
    $keyword = explode("%20",$keywords);
}
else if(stripos($keywords,"+")) {
    $keyword = explode("+",$keywords);
}
```

'$keyword' will then contain your keywords in an array.

Comment: Thanks, but What do you mean by explode by '%20' or explode by '+'?

Comment: explode("%20", $_GET['keywords']);

Comment: Do I put the above explode code in, before, or after if(empty($_GET['keywords'])){$keywords = '';} else {$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];} ?

Comment: Check above. It would be after you retrieved '$keywords'.

Comment: I used your code posted, but the process.php still only retrieves the first word. `if(empty($_GET['keywords'])){$keywords = '';} else {$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];}
$keyword = array();
if(stripos($keywords,"%20")) {$keyword = explode("%20",$keywords);}else if(stripos($keywords,"+")) {$keyword = explode("+",$keywords);}`

Comment: make sure that your string *before* the operation contains the right format. If it does, the code will work. If it does not, then something else is going on to truncate your results.

Comment: The code below is the the first lines of code in the script. `if(empty($_GET['keywords'])){$keywords = '';} else {$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];}
$keyword = array();
if(stripos($keywords,"%20")) {$keyword = explode("%20",$keywords);}else if(stripos($keywords,"+")) {$keyword = explode("+",$keywords);}`

Comment: That doesn't matter. What matters is what is in '$_GET['keywords'] prior to calling any of that code.

Comment: Thanks for all your time, figured it out.  I'll accept your answer.